# while loop not looping despite condition being met

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here's my code so far (well, the while loop):

```
public class Lab10d
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char response = 0;


    //add in a do while loop after you get the basics up and running

        String player = "";

        out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: ");

        //read in the player value
        player = keyboard.next();

        RockPaperScissors game = new RockPaperScissors(player);
        game.setPlayers(player);
        out.println(game);
    while(response == ('y'))
    {
        out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: ");
        player = keyboard.next();
        game.setPlayers(player);
        //game.determineWinner();
        out.println(game);
        out.println();

        //



    }
    out.println("would you like to play again? (y/n):: ");
        String resp =  keyboard.next();
        response = resp.charAt(0);
}
}
```

it's supposed to run the code additional times until an n is inputted

When I input a y, it is supposed to re-run the code but doesn't

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: and you have mismatching brackets? can we see the full code?

Comment: the brackets were off due to the fact i copy/pasted an excerpt of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `while` loop ends before you ask if they want to play again.

Change the loop to:

```
while(response == ('y'))
    {
        out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: ");
        player = keyboard.next();
        game.setPlayers(player);
        //game.determineWinner();
        out.println(game);
        out.println();
        out.println("would you like to play again? (y/n):: ");
        String resp =  keyboard.next();
        response = resp.charAt(0);
    }
```

There is another problem: `response` is not set to 'y' before the loop is started. It will not do anything in the loop at all. Use a `do { ... } while (response == 'y')` loop instead.

```
    do
    {
        out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: ");
        player = keyboard.next();
        game.setPlayers(player);
        //game.determineWinner();
        out.println(game);
        out.println();
        out.println("would you like to play again? (y/n):: ");
        String resp =  keyboard.next();
        response = resp.charAt(0);
    } while (response == 'y');
```

A do-while will execute the code *once*, **then** check the condition and keep executing if it is `true`. A while loop will just check the condition, and keep executing while it's `true`.

EDIT: I put together some code for you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Troubleshoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        char response = ' ';
        do {
            System.out.println("Stuff");
            System.out.print("Again? (y/n): ");
            response = s.next().charAt(0);
        } while (response == 'y');
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Stuff
Again? (y/n): y
Stuff
Again? (y/n): y
Stuff
Again? (y/n): n
```

Comment: he might have set y above, thats not too important, more of the problem is the fact that the loop ends before he asks if he wants to play again. (because of the bracket before out.println)

Comment: looking at his full code you were right about the response not being set, also tell him to set response to 'y' at the top, not 0-or just make it a do-while lol

Comment: @tech_geek23 No, a do-while is guaranteed to always execute once, but a while loop can sometimes not execute at all. A do-while will execute the code *once*, **then** check the condition and keep executing if it is `true`. A while loop will just check the condition, and keep executing while it's `true`.

Comment: changed it to a do-while and it runs it a second time but it's supposed to ask if you want to play again after the initial run as well. and when it asks after the second run, when I put a y it didn't run again

Comment: What it *should* do is run once, then ask if you want to play again, and if you enter 'y' it will keep going. If it doesn't... well, something's wrong in the rest of your code.

Comment: Actually, I think what you're doing is having the response setting code **outside** of the while loop. Try copy-pasting that into the loop. Or just copy-paste my code.

Comment: Here's what my results were just now: Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: S
player had S
 computer had R
 !Computer wins <<Rock Breaks Scissors>>!
Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] ::

Comment: I've also moved it within the code now so that it is `do {
   out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: ");
   player = keyboard.next();
   game.setPlayers(player);
   out.println(game);
   out.println();
   out.println("would you like to play again? (y/n):: ");
   String resp =  keyboard.next();
   response = resp.charAt(0);
   //
   
   
   
  }while(response == ('y')); `

Comment: so it's pretty close to what you suggested if not exact

Comment: it's not even printing "would you like to play again? (y/n):: "?

Comment: got it, i had to add the question to the code before my while-loop so it would ask on the initial run and is correctly working now! Thanks for all your help!